# how to handle string with quotation marks

Tags: r, string, quotation-marks

Hi I try to have some user-input string, what if the string has quotation marks (don't know single/double)?

Specifically, I want to store some R code in a string, e.g.,

```
x = 'a'
y = "b"
```

how do I store this code in a string (later I will use `eval(parse(text=x))` to execute it)

---

Update:

if ask the user to put in the string at `readline()` prompt, R will automatically fix the quotation marks:

```
> readline()
123, "4",  '56'
[1] "123, \"4\",  '56'"
```

I'm looking at how to allow user paste multiple lines

Comment: You can use either to designate it a string, but double quotes are preferred. Here is more information from the R documentation: [https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html)

Comment: "*later I will use eval to execute it*" Why? R is not a macro language.

Comment: `eval(parse(text=x))` you mean

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. The specific context is, we have a software where user can execute R script. But the developers told us that we must use `<-` instead of `=`. I try to store my code as a string, and do the replacement, and do `eval(parse(text=x))` (you're right @amonk thanks-)

Answer (score 2):

You must either escape the quotes

```
x = '\'a\''
y = "\"b\""
```

Or store the string in the alternative of the quotes you want to store

```
x = "'a'"
y = '"b"'
```

Comment: thanks @Conor - is there a way if you don't know what the user's gonna put in?

Comment: What every library you are using to take the input will handle the escaping automatically.

Answer (score -2):

I think you speak about that :-

```
    x = '"' + "Your String" + '"';
```